# Angular 9 and SSR - window is not defined

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-universal, angular9

I am using Angular 9 and SSR and I am getting the error on one of the packages.

```
const DragEvevent = window.DragEvent

ReferenceError: window is not defined
```

On the **ngx-chips** package

We already tried adding to the nodeJs the variables:

```
const domino = require('domino');
const fs = require('fs');
const template = fs.readFileSync(join(join(process.cwd(), 'dist/emaua-front/browser'), 'index.html')).toString();
console.log(template);
const win = domino.createWindow(template);

// mock
global['window'] = win;
global['document'] = win.document;
global['DOMTokenList'] = win.DOMTokenList;
global['Node'] = win.Node;
global['Text'] = win.Text;
global['HTMLElement'] = win.HTMLElement;
global['navigator'] = win.navigator;
```

But still the error persists.

**Update**

```
After updating all packages I got the error: 
ERROR in multi ./src/assets/css/ripple.min.scss ./src/assets/css/lounge.scss ./src/assets/css/discovery.scss ./src/assets/css/main.scss ./src/styles.scss ./node_modules/roboto-fontface/css/roboto/roboto-fontface.css ./node_modules/material-design-icons/iconfont/material-icons.css ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css ./node_modules/ng-bootstrap-to-bootstrap-3/dist/ng-bootstrap-to-bootstrap-3.min.css ./node_modules/jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui.min.css ./node_modules/jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui.theme.min.css ./node_modules/ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css ./node_modules/ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-balham.css ./node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/slick.scss ./node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.scss ./src/assets/css/animate.css ./node_modules/cookieconsent/build/cookieconsent.min.css
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/Users/vinh/learning/front-end/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css' in '/Users/vinh/learning/front-end'
this.debug is not a function
```

After that I applied the fix as said in [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/17604)

And again I am getting the same error like:

```
const DragEvent = window.DragEvent;
                  ^

ReferenceError: window is not defined
```

On the **ngx-chips** package

UPDATE

The problems we have in ngx-chips is something that was happening before.

https://github.com/Gbuomprisco/ngx-chips/issues/740
https://github.com/Gbuomprisco/ngx-chips/issues/786

Does anyone knows a way of overcoming this problem?

Comment: can you try like this

const DragEvevent = (window as any).DragEvent

Comment: What you have should not lead to that error.  Which is the module causing the issue? Also, just checking, did you make sure that the app compiled properly after adding domino, and restart the node/pm2 process? That happend sometimes to me where I'm not debugging latest version of the code...

Comment: @David I updated the module and I tried restarting the process and still the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded to Angular 10 and I had the same problem with ngx-chips on the server.

I solved this problem as follows:
I, probably like many, do not really need this component when rendering on the server.
Too lazy to create a separate project to exclude this module.
So I just disabled this component.

In template:

```
<div *ngIf="isBrowser()">
   <tag-input [(ngModel)]=...  
   </tag-input>
</div>
```

In typescript:

```
isBrowser() {
  if (window) {
       return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```